# flutter_native_admob preload ads

Tags: flutter, admob

is it possible to preload the native flutter admob ads, for example in initState?

I am trying to use the ads in a `ListView.builder()` filled with user-related content and the ads in between. But the ads are loaded too late so that the user can see the spinner appear on screen if he scrolls through the `ListView`.

Example code (from https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_admob):

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: const Text('Plugin example app'),
    ),
    body: ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
          height: 200.0,
          color: Colors.green,
        ),
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
          height: 200.0,
          color: Colors.green,
        ),
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
          height: 200.0,
          color: Colors.green,
        ),
        NativeAdmobBannerView(                // <---- preload this ad
          adUnitID: "<Your ad unit ID>",
          style: BannerStyle.dark, // enum dark or light
          showMedia: true, // whether to show media view or not
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10), // content padding
          onCreate: (controller) {
            controller.setStyle(BannerStyle.light); // Dynamic update style
          },
        ),
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
          height: 200.0,
          color: Colors.green,
        ),
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
          height: 200.0,
          color: Colors.green,
        ),
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
          height: 200.0,
          color: Colors.green,
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, did you got any solution to pre-loading native ads on Flutter?

Comment: Just added the answer. @SlickSlime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the creator of the flutter_native_admob plugin did update the plugin.
You can now wait for the ad to be loaded and render it afterwards. For further info, check the pub-page: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_admob

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_native_admob/flutter_native_admob.dart';
import 'package:flutter_native_admob/native_admob_controller.dart';

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  static const _adUnitID = "<Your ad unit ID>";

  final _nativeAdController = NativeAdmobController();
  double _height = 0;

  StreamSubscription _subscription;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _subscription = _nativeAdController.stateChanged.listen(_onStateChanged);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _subscription.cancel();
    _nativeAdController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _onStateChanged(AdLoadState state) {
    switch (state) {
      case AdLoadState.loading:
        setState(() {
          _height = 0;
        });
        break;

      case AdLoadState.loadCompleted:
        setState(() {
          _height = 330;
        });
        break;

      default:
        break;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Plugin example app'),
        ),
        body: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
              height: 200.0,
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
              height: 200.0,
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
              height: 200.0,
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
            Container(
              height: _height,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
              child: NativeAdmob(
                // Your ad unit id
                adUnitID: _adUnitID,
                controller: _nativeAdController,

                // Don't show loading widget when in loading state
                loading: Container(),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
              height: 200.0,
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
              height: 200.0,
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
              height: 200.0,
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't changing the height of the Ad cause issues with AdMob monitoring if an impression is made or not (amongst other things). And maybe lead to suspension of the AdMob account.

Comment: Can't really answer that question, but i am using it for a good 3 weeks now and it seems to be fine

Comment: @PimVanLommel For me, infinite list view scroll freezes while ad loading. is any fix?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue using some trick. There may be more efficient way, but my solution works properly for me. What I did is:
I create a `NativeAdmob()` widget with the opacity `0`. Once the app is loaded, this widget behaves like `preloaded widget` which never shows on screen.

```
Opacity(opacity: 0, child: NativeAdmob(
                    // Your ad unit id
                    adUnitID: _adUnitID,
                    controller: _nativeAdController,
                    loading: Container(),
                  ),
                ),
```

Then once you trigger another `NativeAdmob()` widget in the same page, the `preloaded ads` will be displayed without any loading process. After showing the first ads, you can refresh it whenever you want using the code line below:

```
_nativeAdController.reloadAd(forceRefresh: true, numberAds: 1);
```